# Predictive model using TensorFlow

Tags: java, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensor

My goal is to generate a predictive model using tensor flow in Java but I first want to ensure that my goal is achievable. Firstly, if I have a bunch of parameters and each set of parameters is assigned an output is it possible to train a model to predict an output given similar parameters? I am able to get hundreds of thousands samples (if needed) in order to train it so is this possible?

Secondly, after the model is trained how fast can it actually generate results?

Lastly, assuming everything up until this point checks out what is the best method in Java’s tensor flow to train a model with data that has multiple parameters associated with an outcome? Also in the result a given piece of data satisfies two results both can be returned as options ordered from most likely to least.

Also just to clarify I am not asking someone to make this for me I am just trying to make sure that a solution exists and is quick (if it’s slow I could just go back to brute forcing which I am trying to move away from since is kinda slow and resource intensive). Also, if you have any pointers on getting started tackling this I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is *very, very* general, but I'll try to offer some insight:

> Firstly, if I have a bunch of parameters and each set of parameters is assigned an output is it possible to train a model to predict an output given similar parameters?

Taking a set of parameters **(known as the feature set X)** and making predictions of another set of parameters **(known as the output set Y)** is the primary purpose of machine learning. Exactly *how* to do this requires many steps, how to do it well takes a lot of experience... However if you are asking if it is possible in principle, that depends on the specific feature set X, and output set Y.

> I am able to get hundreds of thousands samples (if needed) in order to train it so is this possible?

The trick to machine learning is the data must be of a sufficient **quantity *and* quality**. This takes domain specific knowledge to know.

Are you able to provide any specifics about your data to help us understand?